# IRS sale of main home form entry notation

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

In the instructions for IRS Form 8949, it lists out a table of codes that you can put on the form. For the main home sale exclusion, the code is "H". It further explains:

"Report the sale or exchange on Form 8949 as you would if you were not taking the exclusion. Then enter the amount of excluded (nontaxable) gain as a negative number (in parentheses) in column (g). See the example in the instructions for Form 8949, column (g)"

My question is I don't understand "...gain as a negative number (in parentheses) in column (g)."

So lets say I calculated my net gain and it is negative 50000. Do I then put down -50000, (-50000), or (50000) on Form 8949?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: By negative 50,000 do you mean that you lost money on the house?

Answer (score 1):

Your quote [from the 8949 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8949#idm140173103957424) starting with gain is confusing because you are only looking at part of the sentence:

> Report the sale or exchange on Form 8949 as you would if you were not
> taking the exclusion. Then enter the amount of excluded (nontaxable)
> gain as a negative number (in parentheses) in column (g). See the
> example in the instructions for Form 8949, column (g)"

You also have to look at the rest of the row in the table:

> You sold or exchanged your main home at a gain, must report the sale
> or exchange on Part II of Form 8949 (as explained in Sale of Your Home
> in the Instructions for Schedule D (Form 1040 or 1040-SR)), and can
> exclude some or all of the gain

There is an example in the instructions. Unfortunately it is a complex one where there are two codes combined.

> Example.
>
> You sold your main home in 2019 for $320,000 and received a Form
> 1099-S showing the $320,000 gross proceeds. The home's basis was
> $100,000. You had selling expenses of $20,000 that weren’t included on
> your Form 1099-S. Under the tests described in Sale of Your Home in
> the Instructions for Schedule D (Form 1040 or 1040-SR), you can
> exclude the entire $200,000 gain from income. On Form 8949, Part II,
> check box F at the top. Complete columns (a), (b), and (c). Enter
> $320,000 in column (d) and $100,000 in column (e). Enter "EH" in
> column (f). In column (g), enter $220,000 ($20,000 selling expenses +
> $200,000 exclusion) as a negative number. Put it in parentheses to
> show it is negative. In column (h), enter -0- ($320,000 − $100,000 −
> $220,000). If this is your only transaction on this Part II, enter
> $320,000 in column (d) on line 10 of Schedule D (Form 1040 or
> 1040-SR), $100,000 in column (e), ($220,000) in column (g), and -0- in
> column (h).

Pulling the parts relevant to your question, and making up some numbers, you would put

- the sale price in Column D, lets say $450,000
- The cost basis in Column E, lets say $150,000
- The code H in Column F
- The amount you can exude as negative number signified by parentheses: (200,000)

> Column (h)—Gain or (Loss)
>
> Figure gain or (loss) on each row. First, subtract the cost or other
> basis in column (e) from the proceeds (sales price) in column (d).
> Then take into account any adjustments in column (g). Enter the gain
> or (loss) in column (h). Enter negative amounts in parentheses.

So using the numbers from above:

```
 D-E+G
```

or
450,000 - 150,000 + (200,000) = $100,000 in gains that is subject to tax.